# Comparação de horários PHP

Tags: php, data, time

```
date_default_timezone_set ( "America/Sao_Paulo" );
$dtz = new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');
$dt = new DateTime('now', $dtz);
$offset = $dtz->getOffset( $dt ) / 3600;
$por_do_sol = date_sunset(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, -20.7965404, -49.3826269, $zenith = ini_get("date.sunset_zenith"), $offset);
```

adaptei uns script que encontrei na internet... basicamente a variável $por_do_sol é uma string com o horário do por do sol na minha cidade, o que eu quero saber como eu faço pra comparar com o horário atual e saber se já passou o por do sol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer a comparação criando um novo objeto do tipo `DateTime` que receba a hora do pôr do sol na sua cidade, conforme seu exemplo.
Depois disso, é possível criar comparações da forma que desejar, pois a classe `DateTime` utiliza o *timestamp* encapsulado como valor.

Para o seu caso, o código poderá ser o seguinte:

```
﻿<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");

$dt = new DateTime('now');
$offset = $dt->getOffset() / 3600;
$por_do_sol = date_sunset(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, -20.7965404, -49.3826269, $zenith = ini_get("date.sunset_zenith"), $offset);
$dtp = new DateTime($por_do_sol);

if ($dtp < $dt) {
    echo 'Já passou o pôr do sol.';
} else {
    echo 'Não passou o pôr do sol.';
}
```

Obs: Sugiro algumas simplificações, como ao definir a diretiva de `timezone` não será necessário criar um objeto `DateTimeZone` para a construção dos objetos `DateTime`, caso a diretiva informe o mesmo valor do que o objeto, como no exemplo. Para obter o índice da zona horária é possível utilizar a função `getOffset` do seu objeto `DateTime`, pois ele implementa a `DateTimeInterface`.